# how to provide default pointfield value to user location using geolocation API , could not convert string to float:

Tags: django, django-forms, geolocation, geodjango

I'm new to `geodjango` i want to make real-world `gis` project with `geodjango` to find `locations` 
I tried this

```
class Place(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(Account,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True,null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326)
```

views.py

```
class PalceCreateView(CreateView):
    queryset = Place.objects.all()
    def form_valid(self,form):
       lat = self.request.POST['lat']
       lon = self.request.POST['long']
       coords = Point(lat,lon)
       form.instance.location = coords
       form.save()
       return super(PalceCreateView,self).form_valid(form)
```

my forms.py

```
class PlaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Place
       fields = [
          'name','description','location','city','tags'
       ]
       read_only_fields = ['location']
```

my template

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat">
        <input type="hidden" name="long" id="long">

        {{form}}
        <input type='submit' value='submit'>      
</form>
<script>
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
    lat = location.coords.latitude;
    long = location.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML= lat
    document.getElementById('long').innerHTML = long
});
</script>
```

but when I submit the form it will raise this error

> Invalid parameters given for Point initialization.

How can I assign it to a location field?

Comment: Since you are enabling the request to modify the `location` field, why have you added it on the `read_only_fields` of your form?

Comment: i dont want to the user be able to modify the first location which the post was created

Comment: Ok, now I see. I have added an answer that might interest you!

Answer (score 2):

fixed just by using changing the coordinated to float type

```
def form_valid(self,form):
    lat = float(self.request.POST.get('lon'))
    lon = float(self.request.POST.get('lat'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to prevent the user from modifying the initial point and you want to add a second field for a potential point input.

You can achieve this by adding an extra [`form.PointField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/forms-api/#pointfield) directly into the form definition:

```
from django.contrib.gis import forms

class PlaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    new_location = forms.PointField()

    class Meta:
       model = Place
       fields = [
          'name','description','location','city','tags', 'new_location'
       ]
       read_only_fields = ['location']
```

then in your view:

```
class PalceCreateView(CreateView):
    queryset = Place.objects.all()
    def form_valid(self,form):
       new_location = self.request.POST['new_location']
       form.instance.location = new_location
       form.save()
       return super(PalceCreateView,self).form_valid(form)
```

---

Or you can modify your existing solution (`lat, long` as a couple of `form.FloatField`][2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#floatfield)s) as follows:

```
class PlaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lat = forms.FloatField()
    long = forms.FloatField()

    class Meta:
       model = Place
       fields = [
          'name','description','location','city','tags', 'lat', 'long'
       ]
       read_only_fields = ['location']
```

and your view remains the same.